# Trying to select a single item from a <li> and place that value into a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<input type="text" id = "addressbox" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">

<ul class="livesearch" id="livesearch" style="border: 1px solid rgb(165, 172, 178);">
  <li><a href="#">ADDRESS1</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="#">ADDRESS 2</a></li><br>    
</ul>
```

and for javascript

```
$('.livesearch').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("addressbox");
  TheTextBox.value = value;
});
```

When I click on the link it selects all the addresses within the `<ul>` and not the single one I click, example, I click address 1 but in the textbox address1 and address2 show up....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `$('.livesearch')` to `$('.livesearch a')`

Comment: this causes it not to work at all, i tried doing that

Comment: @k_schultz Are you creating `ul` element dynamic?

Comment: try to use only Jquery or only JS... More lisible and maintanable. You've 50/50 here

Comment: @k_schultz Kindly look at my answer and advice not to mix pure JS and jQuery.

Comment: i am creating the ul dynamically

Comment: can I also advice you to change either the class or the id so that they are not the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you even mix pure JavaScript and jQuery? Stick with just one. My strong feeling is that the browser is following the link. Use either `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` to stop the browser from following the link.

Also, please do not use `<br />` unnecessarily. Since you are making a dynamic update of elements, use event delegation like this:

```js
$('.livesearch').on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#addressbox").val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id = "addressbox" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">

<ul class="livesearch" id="livesearch" style="border: 1px solid rgb(165, 172, 178);">
  <li><a href="#">ADDRESS1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ADDRESS 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I add the a to $('.livesearch a').click(function(e) { it breaks the code and no longer works on click

Comment: @k_schultz Looks like a bigger problem? But does it work well in the snippet? Like you wanted?

Comment: Im creating the list dynamically, would that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
$('.livesearch a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).html();
    var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("addressbox");
    TheTextBox.value = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using 100% jQuery:

```js
$('.livesearch a').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  $("#addressbox").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="addressbox" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">

<ul class="livesearch" id="livesearch" style="border: 1px solid rgb(165, 172, 178);">
  <li><a href="#">ADDRESS1</a>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li><a href="#">ADDRESS 2</a>
  </li>
  <br>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your 'this' in :

```
var value = $(this).text();
```

is refering to the tag with the '.livestream' class, namely your whole 'ul'.

You have to replace 'this' by an appropriate selector.